# How to rewrite removeChild from JavaScript to jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this JavaScript in the head of my page.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var nojscss = document.getElementById('nojscss');
    nojscss.parentNode.removeChild(nojscss);
</script>
```

I would like rewrite it in jQuery to run when the page is loading.

I'm pretty new to jQuery do you have an idea how to do it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#nojscss').remove();
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#nojscss").remove();
</script>
```